# Error when exporting the key for Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, keytool

To publish an application to Google Play, you need to export and download the key from Java Keystore.

I executed the specified command and got encryption_public_key.pem:
`keytool -export -rfc -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem`

After that I executed the command: `java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=output.zip --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/path/to/encryption_public_key.pem`

And got an error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QovjD.png)

Error when exporting the key for Google Play

Comment: Please do not post error messages/stack traces as screenshot, just copy and paste the text into your question.